# Does Spring Boot ApplicationRunner.run() run when all beans are created?

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

**Question:** does spring-boot function ApplicationRunner.run() run when **all beans** are created or does it run when *the bean which implements the interface* is built?

For example, given:

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
       // run some logic...
    }
}

@Component 
pubic class OtherClass{
  // ...
}
```

Does MyRunner.run()

- run when both the MyRunner bean and the OtherClass bean are created, **or**
- run when just the MyRunner bean is created and the

  OtherClass bean is not created?

I think the latter is the case based on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html

> public interface ApplicationRunner
>
> Interface used to indicate that a
> bean should run when it is contained within a SpringApplication.
> Multiple ApplicationRunner beans can be defined within the same
> application context and can be ordered using the Ordered interface or
> @Order annotation.

**Why asking the question?**
I am considering to run some logic when my spring-boot application starts. I know both `ApplicationRunner` and `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` can be used for that purpose but do not know which one is better. If `ApplicationRunner.run()` may run while some beans are not created, it will be not reliable for my use case.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve. In one place you say "I am considering to run logic AFTER application started". In other "may run BEFORE all beans are ready". Please edit your question to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: According to [SpringApplication#run](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/148c632299f408a50ba506b1ec79a9938730d3b6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L317) spring-boot fires those beans after context has been refreshed, so, yes, it is safe to use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to run code after spring boot application startup.

- CommandLineRunner interface (with command-line arguments as string array)
- ApplicationRunner interface (with ApplicationArguments instead of string array)
- ApplicationStartedEvent - triggered after context has been refreshed but before command-line and application runners are called
- ApplicationReadyEvent - triggered after any application and command-line runners are called

You can even combine multiple options. They will execute in following order:

1. ApplicationStartedEvent
2. ApplicationRunner or CommandLineRunner depends on @Order
3. ApplicationReadyEvent

[Source: https://stacktraceguru.com/springboot/run-method-on-startup]